# How do the names for the maps in Minecraft work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For my minecraft SMP server, my friends and I were crafting maps and noticed the difference in the names of the maps. so how does the map naming system work?

Example: 
Map_0, Map_1

Comment: Hate to suggest the obvious, but perhaps the number increments in order of creation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first map created is `map_0`, the second created is `map_1`, the third created is `map_2`, and so on, up to `map_65535`. Note that each time you zoom out "one" map, it actually creates a new map with a new map name.

Aside, you can give your maps more memorable names by renaming them in the anvil.

Comment: If you need easier, more canonical names - just put them in an anvil and rename them. E.g. "base 1" "base 2"

Answer (score 4):

When you craft a map, it will be named Map_0 . if you make another map in the same area, it will also be named Map_0 . if you go out of Map_0's boundaries, you can create a new map and it will be called Map_1 . You can keep repeating the process over and over up until Map_65535 . each map in your inventory retains its FOW (Fog of war) covering, even if the maps are the same name. It will also retain FOW when dropping the map and exchanging them.

Hope this answered your question!

Sources: @SevenSidedDie (map numbering), Firsthand experience in Minecraft 1.7.3 (both SSP and SMP), [Yogscast](http://youtube.com/BlueXephos) (Observing map properties in adventure map videos and Update videos)

Answer (score 2):

The map names just help you remember which map is which. The seed is what makes each level different.

Comment: I think he means the map *object* not the world.

Answer (score 2):

Note:  If you hold shift while removing the map you made from the crafting table in SMP, you will craft a copy of Map_0 (the first map ever made on the server, naturally.)

If you want to make a new map centered on a new area, be very careful not to hold shift when you pick up your newly crafted map.

The above is for multiplayer and singleplayer.  I believe singleplayer used to create a copy of whichever map was in your inventory rather than always going for Map_0, but I can't prove it without rolling back (something I'm going to avoid.)